# How to Read in 2d array indexs' from a file (IE: Coords) in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a Game of life program for my cs class, and I have all that well and good (although I wished I used a different structure now, but oh well). The problem I am having is that I cant read our input file correctly. It is set up as such: 1st number is the size of the board for the game of life, then the following lines are pairs of integers separated by a space that show what cells start with life. Then ending in -1 -1 to end it. I have tried several ways and I just cant get it to read it in correctly. I included code for the first way I tried which just involved using Scanner

ex:

```
5

4 1

2 3

-1 -1
```

```
        int x;
        Scanner in = new Scanner (new File(file));
        x= in.nextInt();
        char[][] board= new char[x][x];
            while(in.hasNext())
              {
                if(in.nextInt() != -1)
                board[in.nextInt()][in.nextInt()]='X';
                }//end while
```

Comment: Kurtis, assuming your code compiles, it is almost always helpful to show the Exception stack trace. Whilst it wasn't really needed here, it is worth remembering for future questions. And welcome to StackOverFlow,

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Kevin, will do!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
            if(in.nextInt() != -1)
                board[in.nextInt()][in.nextInt()]='X';
```

When you call `in.nextInt()` in the `if` statement, you move the scanner on to the next int. That way, each loop call you move three integers forward, rather than two.

Set the first `in.nextInt()` to a variable and use the variable in the if statement and the first coordinate of the board. That way you won't move the scanner too far.

Comment: Ohh, I see. That makes sense for the errors I got. Thank you very much, I should be able to complete this now!

Answer (score 1):

You have too many calls to in.nextInt(). Each call to this moves the Scanner onwards.

So, with your if statment you are reading the first co-ordinate int, comparing it to -1.
You then go read another int, which is the second co-ordinate, then yet another int... which should be throwing a NoSuchElementException